# NextJS and caching of pages

Tags: next.js

we are running a nextJS server as a service on a Kubernetes cluster, with a minimum of two replicas. So in a normal situation, we have these:

```
our-nextjs-server-prod-bd7c6dc4c-2dlqg               1/1     Running     0          18h
our-nextjs-server-prod-bd7c6dc4c-7dkbp               1/1     Running     0          18h
```

When the first server is hit for a page it hasn't cached yet, it will work on it, store it in the host node's volume, and will serve it from there in subsequent calls. Now, if the second server is hit for the same page, but is hosted on a different node, it will have to, as I understand it, re-generate the page as it doesn't exist on its node's volume.

Is there a way to have multiple nextJS pods from different nodes utilize a common resource to cache pages? a common volume, an external resource like Redis perhaps? Is there a best practice around that requirement?

*For a moment: Let's disregard the CDN in front of the nextJS service caching the results for a certain TTL. We need those nextJS pods hit frequently so that they can ping the application server for changed properties that'll trigger a re-build of the page.*

Comment: Hey @JasonGenX , I'm facing a similar issue. Did you find a solution to this? Like do you maintain a custom server for caching like redis for caching the generated pages?

Comment: I found no solution for this. There is zero document about how nextJS keeps its cache and how you can pool  a  shared cache by multiple pods/resources.

Comment: Once NextJS creates a cached version of the page, it gets stored in `.next/server/pages`. One idea is to share the this folder in a volume or something like that.

Comment: now there is cache documents : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react cache** to cache your API.

import { cache } from 'react'
. . .

const getLatest = cache(async () => {. . .})